# File sharing from a cable connected pc to wifi connected laptop (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have a one desktop running windows 10  connected to Ethernet cable. And I want to share folder to another wifi connected laptop (also windows 10). Both machines are on the same home internet connection. I have tried to share folders by going to properties > ...

Comment: Check if the computers can see each other by ping-ing the IP/name from one to the other. If the network is set properly, enable File Sharing and after that give permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Specific directions, which you might or might not have followed:

- Open the *Properties* dialog for the folder.
  [image: Setting Sharing]
- Click the *Advanced* button.
- In the *Advanced Security Settings* dialog, select the *Share* tab.
- For test purposes, allow everyone *Full Control*
- Check if that share can be seen from another PC. It sometimes helps to use the [UNC path](https://www.lifewire.com/unc-universal-naming-convention-818230) (e.g. in a Desktop shortcut), `\\PC-NAME\Share` in the above example.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which build your using you could try out this feature.
Microsoft introduced a new [Nearby Sharing](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/97582-turn-off-nearby-sharing-windows-10-a.html) feature starting with [Windows10 build 17035](https://www.tenforums.com/windows-10-news/97563-announcing-windows-10-insider-fast-skip-ahead-build-17035-pc.html).
 Nearby Sharing lets you send and receive content with anyone else nearby using Bluetooth or Wi-Fi.

[image: Near_share.jpg]

Here are the steps to share files using [UWP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Windows_Platform) (Universal Windows Platform) apps from the Share UI in **Windows 10**.

1. To Share File(s) from your **Context Menu** you just click the share option.

[image: Share_context_menu.png]

2. Use the [File Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Explorer) ribbon. To begin sharing, open File Explorer and click on **Properties** in the ribbon section.

[image: properties]

That will open the **Properties** dialog box.

3. Go to **Sharing** tab in the ribbon and click on it and then click on the **share** button.

[image: share_dialog.png]

This will open the **Network Access** window.

4. Now type the name of the user you want to share your files with. And then click the **Add** button.

[image: network_sharing.png]

5. Now select the user and from the **Permission** level drop down menu, you can change its permission whether you want to assign read permission or read/write both. Then press **Share**.

[image: permissions]

Now the folder is shared. Copy the path right below the shared folder using which other users can access it over the network. Click **Done** to finish the process.